# CommandLine Parser verb not recognized

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-parser

I am using the commandline parser to parse 2 verbs. Here is a code snippet:

```
 [Verb("Option1")]
 public class VerbOption1
 {
     [Option('o', "option1")]
     public string Option1 { get; set; }
 }

 [Verb("Option2")]
 public class VerbOption2
 {
     [Option('t', "option2")]
     public string Option2 { get; set; }
 }

Parser.Default.ParseArguments<VerbOption1, VerbOption2>(args)
 .WithParsed<VerbOption1>(option1 => doSomething(option1))
 .WithParsed<VerbOption2>(option2 => doSomethingElse(option2));
```

The issue I am having is that I get an error saying that verb 'x' is not recognized. If I only use 1 verb, then it works. But as soon as I add a second verb I get this error.

Can anyone help to clarify what's happening and how I can resolve this error?

Any hep would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I may be off, but have you checked the example on https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline
? it uses the MapResult method : CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<AddOptions, CommitOptions, CloneOptions>(args)
 .MapResult(
   (AddOptions opts) => RunAddAndReturnExitCode(opts),
   (CommitOptions opts) => RunCommitAndReturnExitCode(opts),
   (CloneOptions opts) => RunCloneAndReturnExitCode(opts),
   errs => 1);

Comment: I reviewed the documentation, however, the issue is with the call to ParseArguement . In order to use MapResult, ParseArguement must return a  parsed object and it is not. It fails with verb not recognized, before I can call MapResult.

Comment: Could you also include the code for your "verbs"? VerbOption1 and VerbOption2

Comment: Good! you can write a proper answer to your question, rather than putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Make sure the verb attribute assigned to the class has a name. Use that name in the command line followed by your options. That was the issue for me. I was using the commandline like I was still processing a single verb, thereby omitting the verb name. The verb name is required when parsing for multiple verbs.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet and the CLI command that you got it to work?

Comment: From the commanline, I was calling things this way:

myprogram.exe -o somevalue.

When in actual fact, I needed to call it this way:

myprogram.exe Option1 -o somevalue,

because I had more then one possible verb to parse for.